# Can not see test modules in module install page

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, tests module can be added with `hidden = TRUE` property in `.info` file to not to display on modules list page, but tests can find and enable them using `protected $modules` property.

But Drupal 8 doesn't have this property and the test modules don't appear in modules list page. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Test modules are under `module_name/tests/` or `module_name/tests/directory` and can be enabled by [`TestDiscovery`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.5.x/core/modules/simpletest/src/TestDiscovery.php) service. As `ExtensionDiscovery::scan()` calls `TestDiscovery::getExtensions()` method with `$include_test` flag `TRUE`.

The flag can be overridden by settings:
    if (!isset($include_tests)) {
      $include_tests = Settings::get('extension_discovery_scan_tests') || drupal_valid_test_ua();
    }

See also [ExtensionDiscovery::scanDirectory](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.5.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionDiscovery.php#L434)
 and [RecursiveExtensionFilterIterator::acceptTests()](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.5.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/Discovery/RecursiveExtensionFilterIterator.php#L110)

For manually enabling and testing a test module, it could be moved under modules directory (from /tests) and move back once development done to enable it via test.